# Web API Post won't bind data to method parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I hate to ask because there are many questions dealing with this issue, but I haven't gotten any to post any data to an ASP.NET Web API 2 method.  This is all coming and going to the same host and port.

Here's my server side code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/help")]
public class HelpAPIController : ApiController
...
public class Item {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
}

[Route]
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] Item[] stuff)
        ;  // we get here but data is always null or zero items in array
}
```

Javascript:

```
"use strict";
var a = [{ "name": "me", "position": "here" }, 
         { "name": "me", "position": "here" }, 
         { "name": "me", "position": "here" }];

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "application/json",
    url: "/api/help/",
    data: { "stuff": JSON.stringify(a) },
    success: function (data) { alert(data); },
    error: function (error) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Actual request content (no hard returns):

```
stuff:[{"name":"me","position":"here"},
       {"name":"me","position":"here"},
       {"name":"me","position":"here"}]
```

Comment: Does it work with a `List<Item>` instead of `Item[]`?

Comment: @PetreTurcu Nope, and it doesn't even work with a single object without the array (when both server and client do not specify an array.)  It has zero items or empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are not passing a content type to the server. `datatype` is what response type you expect from the server. `contentType` is what you are sending. The default `contentType` in jQuery is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. You need to add/edit:

   ```
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json",
   ```
2. You don't need to wrap the data array with an object. This will do:

   ```
   data: JSON.stringify(a),
   ```

Comment: Yep.  Needed both contentType and the JSON.stringify(a) change.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `contentType: "application/json"` in your Ajax POST.

You have dataType, which I think is what you expect back from server whereas contentType is what you are sending.

Comment: Definitely correct on the contentType, but also had to change the stringify part too.  The contentType was 90% part of the solution.  I wish I could mark two answers correct.